# When does AngularJs re-evaluate a bound function?

Tags: angularjs

Sorry if this question is too dumb. I'm new in AngularJs!

Lets say there are two elements on a page:
one `input` texbox bound to `name` of `$scope`. Another is a `<p>` bound to `getTime` function of `$scope` to evaluate current time. This page can be found in this plunker [here](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/7T0PZzzS6wdjxJXhJ3DV?utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=worker&utm_campaign=next&preview)

```
  <body ng-controller="Controller">
    <h1>{{message}}, {{name}}</h1>
    <h2>{{getTime()}}</h2>
    <input type = "text" ng-model = "name">
  </body>
```

```
  $scope.getTime = function(){
    return new Date();
  }
```

The function gets called only once. However, if I enter a value in the textbox, the function immediately fires. I don't understand the relation between these two events. Hopefully, somebody can shed a light here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view must display the value returned by `getTime()`.

So it needs to *call* `getTime()` to know what it returns.

But AngularJS can't possibly know what `getTime()` does. Maybe `getTime()` returns the value entered in the textbox in reverse order. Or maybe not. It can't know.

What it does know, however, is that when the user enters something in the input field, some values of the scope will be modified. And that could thus change the value computed and returned by `getTime()`.

So it calls `getTime()` again to know if it returns something different than before, and to display the new value if it has changed.

This is basically what happens. It's actually more complex than that, because changing a value in the scope will trigger watchers, which in turn can change other values in the scope, etc. etc. So this process is repeated a number of times, until everything is stable. That is called the digest loop. It can run up to 10 iterations, and then fails with an error.

So, to answer your question:

> When does AngularJs re-evaluate a bound function?

A lot of time. Every time any AngularJS event (ng-click, ng-mouseenter, a $http response coming back, a $interval which fires, etc.) occurs in the application, and more than once for each event.

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the concept of `digest loop`

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand the relation between these two events. Hopefully,
>   somebody can shed a light here.

When you have `{{ getTime() }}` you instruct AngularJS to call a function each and every time the page need to be reevaluated.

This is *exactly* the same as if you rendered out a scope variable like `{{ currentTime }}`; if `currentTime` had been changed in code since last evaluation cyklus, for example by `$scope.currentTime = new Date()` then a new timestamp would be rendered out as well.

So there is no magic or wrong here, it works as expected. You just notice it because time always changes, and your `getTime()` method is called each time the page is rerendered.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

During the compilation phase:

- the [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) and [input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) set up a keydown listener on the `<input>` control.
- the [interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) sets up a [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) to be notified of `getTime()`changes.

During the runtime phase:

- Pressing an `'X'` key causes the browser to emit a `keydown` event on the input control.
- The input directive captures the change to the input's value and calls [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)`('name="X"')` to update the application model inside the AngularJS execution context.
- AngularJS applies the `name = 'X';` to the model.
- The [$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) loop begins
- The [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) list executes `getTime()`
- AngularJS exits the execution context, which in turn exits the `keydown` event and with it the JavaScript execution context.
- The browser re-renders the view with the updated text.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the Browser Event Loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

---

## Update

If the goal is to have the time continuously updated, use the [$interval Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("Controller",function($scope,$interval) {
    $scope.message = "Hello ";
    var promise = $interval(function() {
        $scope.currentTime = new Date();
    }, 500);
    $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        $interval.cancel(promise);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">
    <h1>{{message}}, {{name}}</h1>
    <h2>{{currentTime | date : 'hh:mm.ss.sss'}}</h2>
    <input type = "text" ng-model = "name">
</body>
```

The [$interval service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) automatically triggers a digest cycle on each interval event.

For more information, see [AngularJS $interval Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)